# Collapsing Table Rows via Jquery

Tags: jquery

Im trying to build a table. The table consists of the following. Each line is a row.

```
Main-Parent
 + Parent
  - children
  - children
 + Parent
  - children
  - children
```

The children will collapse into their Parent. And each of the parents will collapse into the Main Parent.
Ive got it partially working but not fully. 
You can see the behavior in http://jsfiddle.net/0Lh5ozyb/88/

**HTML**

```
<table class="table">
    <tr class="main-parent" id="">
        <td><div>MAIN PARENT</div></td>
        <td><div>MAIN PARENT</div></td>
        <td><div>MAIN PARENT</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parent sub" id="row1">
        <td><div>PARENT</div></td>
        <td><div>PARENT</div></td>
        <td><div>PARENT</div></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="child-row1-1 sub">
        <td><div>CHILD</div></td>
        <td><div>Jackson</div></td>
        <td><div>94</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child-row1-2 sub">
        <td><div>CHILD</div></td>
        <td><div>Doe</div></td>
        <td><div>80</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="parent sub" id="row2">
        <td><div>PARENT</div></td>
        <td><div>PARENT</div></td>
        <td><div>PARENT</div></td>
    </tr>

    <tr class="child-row2-1 sub">
        <td><div>CHILD</div></td>
        <td><div>Jackson</div></td>
        <td><div>94</div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="child-row2-2 sub">
        <td><div>CHILD</div></td>
        <td><div>Doe</div></td>
        <td><div>80</div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**JQUERY**

```
// main heading
$('tr.main-parent')
    .css("cursor", "pointer")
    .click(function () {
        var $children = $(this).nextUntil($('tr').not('.sub'));
        $children.find('td > div, td').slideToggle();
});
$('tr[class^=child-]').find('td > div, td').hide();

// parent heading
$('tr.parent')
    .css("cursor", "pointer")
    .click(function () {
        var $children = $(this).nextUntil($('tr').not('[class^=child-]'));
        $children.find('td > div, td').slideToggle();
});
$('tr.sub').find('td > div, td').hide();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

slideToggle can't be used for the main heading because the child headings may be in mixed states of visibility. You were simply inverting which subheadings were visible.

If at least one is visible you need them all to close.

```
// main heading
$('tr.main-parent')
    .css("cursor", "pointer")
    .click(function () {

        var $children = $(this).nextUntil($('tr').not('.sub'));

        if ($children.find(':visible').length) {
            $children.find('td > div, td').slideUp();
        }       
        else {
            $children.find('td > div, td').slideDown();
        }
});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/0Lh5ozyb/120/

**EDIT**

If you would like to only show the subheadings when opening the main heading, filter to them first:

```
$children.filter('.parent').find('td > div, td').slideDown();
```

Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/0Lh5ozyb/133/

Comment: Thanks - if you collapse everything and then main parent. If you expand, everything is shown. Anyway to change that.

Comment: certinaly did, thanks. though jyst trying to sort out the jerky ness when i apply this to my real life tables which are largish.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30608747/table-with-slidetoogle-randomly-jerky